# Explanation of three css lines

Tags: css, html-lists

Can anybody explain for me the difference between these three:

```
1.  ul li a:hover
2.  #drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul 
3.  #drop-nav ul li:hover > ul
```

The most difficault part is when there are more than one ul and li. I dont understand what they mean. Ive tried to google it, and if you know any good articles on exactly this I would really appreciate that!

Comment: have you tried playing around with using this CSS on a webpage while selectively removing different lines? maybe you will notice different behaviours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `ul li a:hover` target a hover-ed `a` element that is contained within a `li` element. This `li` element must in turn be contained in an `ul` element. In short, it target something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>This element satisfy "ul li a:hover"</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a>This element also satisfy "ul li a:hover"</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice how in the second example the `<a>` tag is not a direct child of the `<li>` tag? As long as it's contained within a `<li>` tag the selector would still be satisfied.

---

2- `#drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul` is 2 different CSS selectors that target 2 different types of element. They share the same styles that are defined after. The 2 selectors are `#drop-nav ul li:hover` and `ul li ul`. The `,` selector group 2 group together and give them the same style.

`#drop-nav ul li:hover` targets hover-ed `li`s that are contained in an `ul`, which is contained within an element which have `id="drop-nav"`.

`ul li ul` targets `ul`s that are contained within a `li`, which is contained within another `ul`.

So either this:

```
<div id="drop-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>This element satisfy "#drop-nav ul li:hover", so it also satisfy "#drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul"</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>This element satisfy "ul li ul", so it also satisfy "#drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul"</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Will satisfy your selector.

---

3- `#drop-nav ul li:hover > ul`: the `>` selector is a "direct child" selector. This whole thing target `ul`s that is the direct child of a hover-ed `li` element, which is contained within an `ul`, which is contained within an element with `id="drop-nav"`. Meaning the html is something like this:

```
<div id="drop-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>This element satisfies "#drop-nav ul li:hover > ul"</ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that this will not satisfy the rule this time:

```
<div id="drop-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <ul>This element does NOT satisfy "#drop-nav ul li:hover > ul"</ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because the `ul` is not a direct child of a `li`. Its direct parent is a `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
1. ul li a:hover
```

It mean css work for element `<a></a>` when mouse over, inside element `ul li`

```
2.  #drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul
```

It mean css work for element `<li></li>` when mouse over inside element with id `drop-nav ul li` and also work for element `<ul></ul>` inside `ul li` with same css

```
3.  #drop-nav ul li:hover > ul
```

symbol `>` it mean css only work for `ul` which have 1 level below `li:hover` or inline with `li:hover`

Answer (score 0):

### `ul li a:hover`

This style takes place when you hover over this `a` element.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">This link will change on hover</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### `#drop-nav ul li:hover , ul li ul`

The comma separates two different selectors. The first is this:

```
<div id="drop-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>This li will change on hover</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The second is this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>This is a nested unordered list</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### `#drop-nav ul li:hover > ul`

This style only affects the immediate `ul` children of the selector.

```
<div id="drop-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>This ul is affected when the li is hovered.</ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="drop-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>
        <ul>This ul is NOT affected when the li is hovered.</ul>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Works for links in unnumbered list elements only if cursor is over the `<a>` tag area
2. Applied for hovered list elements if list parent has id specified and for all unnumbered 2nd level lists
3. Appleid for 2nd level lists if parent element of first level list has specified id and cursor is over of first level (parent) list element

If you see more then one list it means the sublevel is present. Please use classes instead of id if it's possible.